# Applescript to open URLs with a specific name in a new tab?

Tags: google-chrome, applescript

I have a very specific request because I have a very specific annoyance with one of my jobs. I grade for an online school and we have hundreds and hundreds of submissions in the web portal that we need to grade. The way the admins have set up the site, each submission is behind its own link and you click the "View" button/link to open each individual assignment in a new tab, grade it then just close that tab.

So it can take me the majority of my time just opening all these tabs, not to mention they are all in a table view, so sometimes I miss one or I open one twice, etc.

I have the start of a script but I am off because all it is doing is re-opening the main page that shows ALL the submissions (So each "View" link does have its own specific number behind it for the code to that specific submission, I tried to take just the number off but it's not working...):

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat with w in windows
        set i to 1
        repeat with t in tabs of w
            if URL of t starts with "https://SCHOOLURL.org/submissions/view" then
                set active tab index of w to i
                set index of w to 1
                return
            end if
            set i to i + 1
        end repeat
    end repeat
    open location "https://SCHOOLURL.org/submissions/view"
end tell
```

I tried to use another script and alter it but it only opens the main page again, not the links.

Comment: Where do you get the unique part of the URL from?

Comment: It comes from the lessons submission number, each lesson has its own submission number at the end of the URL. I'm assuming they just keep going up +1 with each new submission.

Comment: Looking through your script… I don't see where it is used though. This is likely why you're always sent to the main page. You need to get the URL that's connected to the 'view' link. As an aside, what happens if you command-click on one of the view links? Does it open the correct assignment in a separate tab?